# Twitter header text

Tags: asp.net, twitter

I wish to create an application and have a button that post a tweet to my twitter account.  I have this code found in the net.  The code is great but I have one problem.  when I click the button a pop up window opens but the text above the textbox is "What's happening?."

My question now, how to change this text?

Please see codes below.

Thanks

RJUY

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="FacebookUserImport.Twitter.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <!-- other smart stuff here... -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function popup_share(url, width, height) {
            day = new Date();
            id = day.getTime();
            eval("page" + id + " = window.open(url, '" + id + "', 'toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,location=1,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=0,width=" + width + ", height=" + height + ", left = 363, top = 144');");
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- other smart stuff here... -->
    <% var link = "Practice: some text here http://www.florian-hacquebart.eu/?p=113',800,320"; %>
    <a href="javascript:popup_share('http://twitter.com/home?status=<%= link %>)" title="Share on Twitter">
        <img src="twitter_button.png" alt="share this article on twitter" />
    </a>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are opening a part of the Twitter website (`http://twitter.com/home?status=...`) , so you cant change the content on this Window.